# Color a a general graph with maximal degree $\Delta$ using $2^{O(\Delta)}$ colors within $\log^{*}n$ rounds

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, graphs, distributed-systems, colorings

Consider the following algorithm $A$ to 6-color an rooted tree within $\log^{*}n$ rounds in a distributed system:

1: Assume that initially the nodes have IDs of size $\log(n)$ bits

2: The root is assigned the label $0$, and each other node $v$ is assigned $c(v) = ID_v$

3: Each other node $v$ executes the following:

3.1: send its own color $c(v)$ to all children

3.2: receive the color $c(p_v)$ from its parent

3.3: interpret $c(v)$ and $c(p_v)$ as bit-strings

3.4: set $i$ to be the index of the smallest bit where $c(v)$ and $c(p_v)$ differ

3.5: set the new value of $c(v)$ to be: $<i \text{ (as bitstring)}, i\text{-th bit of } c(v)_\text{old}>$

3.6: until $c(w) \in  \{0, . . . , 5\}$ for all nodes $w$

Now, I want to use algorithm $A$ for a coloring of a general graph of $n$ vertices with a maximal degree of $\Delta$.
I want a $2^{O(\Delta)}$ coloring within $\log^{*}n$ rounds.

Now, my intuition was do the same algorithm $A$, but with a few modifications.
Naturally, the stages that should be modified are stages 3.5 and 3.6.
My idea was to that each vertex $v$ send its own current color $c(v)$ to each of its neighbors.
Then, comes the part which I'm not sure about. I thought about denoting the same $<i, i\text{-th bit of } c(v)_\text{old}>$ for each neighbor $w$ of $v$, and then concatenate the outcomes.
Since there are at most $\Delta$ neighbors, this will lead to at most $\Delta$ substring that create the new value of $c(v)$.
However, I'm not sure how to continue from here, or whether what I'm doing is the correct way.

Help would be appreciated.